# WP_User_Query Custom Field meta_query with Date clause

Tags: wp-user-query

I have a custom meta field 'bhaa_runner_dateofrenewal' which records the date that a User on my system last renewed their membership, the field format is YYYY-MM-DD. I'm trying to write a custom query which will query and order the list of returned users by year.

I came across this [custom-field-multiple-clauses](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/125969/custom-field-multiple-clauses) post which outlines how the 'date()' function can be used in the value field

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 100,
    'post_type' => 'create_events',
    'meta_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'key' => 'startDate',
                'value' => date('Y-m-d'),
                'compare' => '>='
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'endDate',
                'value' => date('Y-m-d'),
                'compare' => '<='
            ),
    'orderby'  => 'meta_value', 
    'meta_key' => 'startDate',
    'order' => 'DESC'
    )
);
$custom_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

My custom query looks like this at the moment but it is using a String LIKE comparison of the 'bhaa_runner_dateofrenewal' field value.

```
$usersByCompanyArgs = new WP_User_Query(
    array(
        'fields' => 'all_with_meta',
        'orderby' => 'bhaa_runner_dateofrenewal',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'bhaa_runner_company',
                'value' => $this->houseid,
                'compare' => '='),
            array(
                'key' => 'bhaa_runner_dateofrenewal',
                'value' => '2014',
                'compare' => 'LIKE')
        )
    )
);
```

Does anybody know how i might update the clause to that i can treat the field as a real date, and use the custom MYSQL YEAR() function here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the type of the data in your `meta_query`.

Unfortunately, you can only use the comparison `BETWEEN` if your date is in the format `YYYYMMDD`. So to see the users for one year, you would have to set your metaquery like this:

```
$usersByCompanyArgs = new WP_User_Query(
    array(
        'fields' => 'all_with_meta',
        'orderby' => 'bhaa_runner_dateofrenewal',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'bhaa_runner_company',
                'value' => $this->houseid,
                'compare' => '='),
            array(
                'key' => 'bhaa_runner_dateofrenewal',
                'value' => '2014-01-01', // date to compare to, before this one
                'compare' => '<',
                'type' => 'DATE' //set the format
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'bhaa_runner_dateofrenewal',
                'value' => '2013-01-01', // date to compare to, after this one
                'compare' => '>=',
                'type' => 'DATE' //set the format
            ),
        )
    )
);
```

If your Date field was formated `YYYYMMDD` you could replace the two comparisons in the `meta_query` with

```
            array(
                'key' => 'bhaa_runner_dateofrenewal',
                'value' => array( '20130101', '20140101' ), // date to compare to, after this one
                'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
                'type' => 'DATE' //set the format
            )
```