# Wordpress where clauses in db select

Tags: database, users

I'm currently struggling with implementing a feature for wordpress site. I would like to get the count of all users which have the key `pending_approval='true'` and `is_photographer='true'` (located in `wp_usermeta`. How could that be achieved? I've been searching through the documentation, but I couldn't find an proper example.

Example code:

```
$users_sent_to_admin = new WP_User_Query(array(
                                             'meta_query' => array(
                                                 array(
                                                     'key' => 'pending_approval',
                                                     'value' => 'true',
                                                     'compare' => '='),
                                                 array(
                                                     'key' => 'is_photographer',
                                                     'value' => 'true',
                                                     'compare' => '='
                                                 ),
                                             )
                                         ));

$users_sent_to_admin = new WP_Query($users_sent_to_admin);
```

Comment: I've just updated my question. This code doesn't return anything for some reason - and I'm sure there is data in the database. I'm not sure if it's correct or syntax. I've copied it from http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/131351/wp-user-query-custom-field-meta-query-with-date-clause

Comment: Are you sure the boolean value `'true'` is stored as string? Isn't it more likely to be `1`? I'm just guessing here as I don't have any pending users.

Comment: Yes, the variable is stored as a string. Is that, though, the correct way to get the data from the database? I'm kind of new to wordpress...

Comment: Are you sure there are users matching the query logic?

Comment: After I debugged it a bit more, I found out I was just not using the `$users_sent_to_admin` after that... The code above works just fine. I didn't know I had to call `$users_sent_to_admin->get_results()` after the query. Previously I was using `get_users()` and it was returning the users right away, so I presumed the `WP_Query` would give me the results.... Thank you all for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing the `relation` key here. If you want the users to be picked up when both the above meta values are matched, then you should use this as below

```
$users_sent_to_admin = new WP_User_Query(
                        array(
                            'meta_query' => array(
                                'relation' => 'AND',
                                array(
                                    'key' => 'pending_approval',
                                    'value' => 'true',
                                    'compare' => '='),
                                array(
                                    'key' => 'is_photographer',
                                    'value' => 'true',
                                    'compare' => '='
                                ),
                            )
                        )
                    );
```

Comment: Both solutions(yours and mine) return the right content, so I'll accept your answer.